# Why cannot a Lock for `2`-threads be implemented using only `1` shared variable satisfying mutual exclusion and deadlock freedom?

Tags: multithreading

I've been working a lot with concurrency at the practical level, and therefore I've also started to study it theoretically to gain insight into this field of computer science.

However, I've trouble understanding the following:

Why cannot a Lock for `2`-threads be implemented using only `1` shared variable satisfying mutual exclusion and deadlock freedom?

More generally, why is at least `n` shared variables needed for a `n`-thread lock satisfying mutual exclusion and deadlock freedom?

Consider two threads `A` and `B`. I see that `A` must write to this variable in order to signify it acquires the lock. The variable could be a boolean. Is it because that `A` needs to read the variable before writing it, and this is two operations? (not done atomically)

Comment: It's definitely because of some set of assumptions about what operations you can and can't perform, and you haven't told us what your assumptions are. You're probably assuming that you have perfect memory visibility and ordering but no atomic read-modify-write operations.

Comment: read, write and such simple instructions are atomic.

Comment: Right, but what about read-modify-write operations such as increment or test and set?

Comment: Read/Write locks are generally implemented with a single variable that stores both the write and read counts... Which is basically two locks. Hence the assumption that it's impossible to do so is wrong.

Comment: @Voo Sure, but that count is accessed with an atomic read-modify-write operation. I believe the OP is assuming perfect memory visibility and perfect ordering but no read-modify-write operations.

Comment: @David possibly, but the way this is currently phased the answer is just "it's possible". And those assumptions would be completely unrealistic anyhow I'm sure you agree. We're not in the 70s any more.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, you're reading things that make assumptions about the platform's capabilities that are no longer realistic. You're probably considering the case where a CPU has no prefetching, no posted writes, total read and store ordering, no compiler optimization that affect memory visibility or memory operation ordering, and no risk of word tearing, but does not have an atomic "read-modify-write" operation like increment or compare-exchange. With these assumptions, there's really no way to do it with one variable.

This is an interesting theoretical problem, but has very little practical relevance. Modern CPUs do have all of those optimizations -- they prefetch reads, they post writes to buffers, they re-order reads and stores, and compilers optimize away memory options. Word tearing is typically not an issue for aligned operations to native integer types. But, more importantly, modern CPUs have sophisticated, high-performance atomic operations such as increment, decrement, compare-exchange, and so on.

When you write synchronization primitives, the exercise is highly platform-specific. The combination of capabilities available to you varies from platform to platform. Even more importantly, their costs vary drastically from platform to platform, so even if many solutions are possible, they may not be equally good.

Lastly, you have to have a deep understanding of what each primitive actually makes the platform do. For example, on modern Intel CPUs, there is hyper-threading. It's important that, for example, a thread waiting for a spinlock doesn't starve another thread sharing the physical core. That requires deep understanding of how hyper-threading actually works. Similarly, it's easy to code a spinlock so that you take the mother of all mispredicted branches when you acquire the lock and blow out the pipelines at the instant where performance is the most critical. You need to understand how branch prediction works and how it interacts with instruction pipelining to avoid this issue.

The vast majority of programmers should never, ever write synchronization primitives and use them in actual, real world code. Getting them to work with assured reliability is hard, and getting them to perform properly is much, much harder. And to top it off, it's not possible to measure their performance easily. (Of course, it's great to experiment, so long as you don't get an exaggerated sense of the usefulness of your experimental code.)